# ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, aes, xor

I am trying to encrypt strings. but getting this error:-

> ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

key = 'E61EFD66173C8A58132B84E43566AB4826533F4483968BA58C9C4739FFD25FAD'
firstByte = key[0:32]
lastByte = key[32:64]

hexfirstByte = firstByte.encode()
hexlastByte = lastByte.encode()
# xorNumber = int(firstByte,2) ^ int(lastByte,2)
xorNumber = hex(int(firstByte,16) ^ int(lastByte,16))
hexNumber = bytes(xorNumber, 'utf-8')    
IV = 16 * '\x00'
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
encryptor = AES.new(hexNumber, mode, IV=IV)

text = 'j' * 64 + 'i' * 128
ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)

decryptor = AES.new(hexNumber, mode, IV=IV)
plain = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print("decript" + str(plain))
```

Comment: Before the problematic line try to print the lengths of the input parameters and from there find where the error is. Also post the whole error traceback. Does the error happen on the line `AES.new`?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ Error showing in this line:- `encryptor = AES.new(hexNumber, mode, IV=IV)`

Comment: I don't really see what causes the error, I'd try putting print before that line and testing the length of the hexNumber, since the error complains about that. Have you tried it?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ length is 34

Comment: have you tried testing why that is? I'm not going to help you with the whole thing. Try printing it and couting the charcters. Maybe there is a leftover `0x` at the start of the `hexNumber` left over from `xorNumber`.